# can not ssh on the floating ip given by openstack to the ubuntu cloud server image

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

i created an instance of Ubuntu server cloud image on Open-stack with an associated SSH Key pair and floating IP assigned to it. I can not ssh on the floating IP and neither ping works on the IP. When i open the instance in the console of open-stack, It asks me for username and password!

I have tried to access it with the private IP instead of floating IP but it doesn't work as well. I have configured Open-stack on the physical IP address of host.

ssh -i key.pem cirros@172.24.4.212

I have configured the openstack on the physical machine on the physical IP address of the machine.

Comment: Hi have you setup your security group to allow access via port 22? Also you need to allow ICMP traffic in order to get ping response from the port assigned to the instance.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue by allowing the ICMP ports in the security groups and then successfully ssh the instance with the key. Now the problem I have is that the instance floating ip can be pinged from the system and instance but it can not access the public internet. Do you have any info how to allow the instance to access the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many reasons for this problem, is possible your provider network is missconfigured, e.g. you has set wrong segmentation, external bridge down, wrong bridge-mappings, etc.

But assuming you has configured everything fine, then the problem would be in your Neutron ports.

If your OpenStack deployment has been deployed with Neutron port security, you would need to setup your security groups first, then make sure at least one security bridge has been assigned to your instance.

You can add a security group rule by using the OpenStack API:

```
$ openstack security group rule create SECURITY_GROUP_NAME --protocol tcp --dst-port 22:22 --remote-ip 0.0.0.0/0

$ openstack security group rule create --protocol icmp SECURITY_GROUP_NAME
```

Or just use your Horizon GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue my editing the security group settings and allowing the ICMP ports. This issue is related to port 22 of ICMP but i allowed all the ports on TCP, ICMP and UDP and then i was able to ssh the instance.